# how to get in my app the activities from my friends using the same action type/objects?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

i create a new action type **ler** (translation for 'read' in my language) and a object called **reportagem** (similar for built-in object 'news').

i tried this at graph api explorer:

```
me/friends/reportagem.lerem
```

according to the configuration of my action type and object, that should be the correct way to find my friends activities in my app.

thanks in advance.

Comment: just for information, my app is not submitted for the app center. i realize now that this could be the problem. none of my custom action types and object is validated for facebook yet. but... i couldn't retrieve the activities of the others developers using that url in open graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see your Friend's activity for a given action, you must query the Graph API using the Action ID, not the `namespace.action` method.

Example, my Action ID is: `1234567890`

If I want to read the actions of my friends for the same action, call the Graph API as follows:

`GET https://graph.facebook.com/friend.name/1234567890`

If you have permission, the above call will list the friend's actions from the App.

You can get the Action ID from the `Open Graph` section from the `App Settings` page. Check the URL (it will be something like):

`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{app_id}/opengraph/action_type/{action_id}`

Comment: what permission should i have for read this informations? **friends_activities**?

Comment: You will need to ask for `user_actions:APP_NAMESPACE` and `friends_actions:APP_NAMESPACE`. If you are using built-in actions, you can also ask for `friends_actions:music`, `friends_actions:news` etc.